# I have a question about a proof I am doing with partial ordered sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$L$ is a partially ordered set in which every subset has a least upper bound. Suppose that $L$ has a bottom element. Prove that $L$ is a complete lattice.

I understand that I need to show that any subset has a GLB.

So I can take some set, $S$ and talk about the set $T$ of all lower bounds for $S$. We know $T$ is nonempty because our bottom element is in it, and we have that $T$ has a least upper bound, call is $s$. Now I can easily show that if the least upper bound is actually in $T$ then its the greatest lower bound of $S$. But what if $s$ is not in $T$? Then it's not a lower bound for $S$ and I am confused.

any help would be great.

Comment: You are saying that *every* subset has a LUB. Then what is the LUB of the empty set? Isn't that automatically a bottom element?

Comment: My instructor said that the writer(kaplansky) of this book, for some reason, leaves out things he should not. I assume he means nonempty set.

Comment: By (the standard) definition, a complete lattice has the property that every set **without exception** has a least upper bound, which implies that every set has a greatest lower bound, and that there is a top element and a bottom element.

Comment: On the other hand, the weaker property "every **nonempty** set **which is bounded above** has a least upper bound" implies that every nonempty set which is bounded below has a greatest lower bound; it does **not** imply a top or bottom element, and is famously true of the real line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every element of $T$ is a lower bound for $S$, it follows that every element of $S$ is an upper bound for $T$. (Either way, we're just saying that each element of $T$ is $\le$ each element of $S$.) Since $s$ is the **least** upper bound of $T$, it follows that $s\le$ every upper bound of $T$, in particular, $s\le$ every element of $S$, i.e., $s$ is a lower bound for $S$, which means that $s\in T$.